# Delete firsts character from text file

Tags: python, text-files

I have an issue with writing in a text file with Python

I have a big text file, and I want to delete the nth first character
I wrote a function like this:

```
def get_texte():
 f = open("hp.txt", "r+",encoding="utf8")
 texte = ''
 nb = 12
 for line in f.readlines():
    texte += line.strip()
 texte1 = texte[nb:]
 f.truncate(0)
 f.write(texte1)
 f.close()
 return texte
```

When I call the function, the file is well emptied; texte1 is well calculated, but it refuses to write texte1 on the file, which remains empy. Do you know why?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean to return `texte`? I think you need to return something else

Comment: About "truncate" the docs say "The current stream position isn’t changed." so I guess you need a "seek" after "truncate".

Comment: Doesn't `truncate(0)` make the file empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose two ways to do this.

**To write in end of opened file:**

```
texte = ''
nb = 12
with open("ph.txt", "r+",encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        texte += line.strip()
    texte1 = texte[nb:]
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(texte1)
```

**To overwrite the opened file:**

```
texte = ''
nb = 12
with open("ph.txt", "r+",encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        texte += line.strip()
    texte1 = texte[nb:]
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(texte1)
```